# Copy-Item for copy files from local to remove server using credentials

Tags: windows, powershell, file-copying, windows-scripting, copy-item

I am trying to copy some files and folder from my local machine to a remote server:

```
Copy-Item .\copy_test.txt -destination "\\serverip\c$\backups\"
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
Copy-Item : Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
At line:1 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  .\copy_test.txt -destination "\\serverip\c$\backups\" -verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

I was trying using credentials but this command does not allow `-Credential` argument. I was searching a lot and in every example the command is pretty easy just executing the `Copy-Item $source -destination $destination` and I wonder why is so hard in my workstation.

### Creating New PSDrive

I tried to create a `New-PSDrive` but it didn't work.

```
$creds = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\$serverip\c$' -Credential $creds -Persist
Copy-Item '.\copy_test.txt' -Destination 'X:\backups'
Remove-PSDrive -Name X
```

It is the error message:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop> .\copyfiles.ps1
New-PSDrive : The network path was not found
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\copyfiles.ps1:11 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\$serverip\c$' -Credential $c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (X:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveC

Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'X' does not exist.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\copyfiles.ps1:12 char:1
+ Copy-Item '.\copy_test.txt' -Destination 'X:\backups'
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (X:String) [Copy-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Remove-PSDrive : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'X' does not exist.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\copyfiles.ps1:13 char:1
+ Remove-PSDrive -Name X
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (X:String) [Remove-PSDrive], DriveNotFoundExcepti
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemovePSDriveCommand
```

### My servers

My server are windows instances in AWS. I have the right permission because I am able to run other command like `Invoke-Command` in order to inspect some services into the remote server.

```
PS> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Comment: `New-PSDrive` _Create a temporary or persistent mapped network drive_  could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using PowerShell version 4.0 and then upgrade my version to 5.0

In previous version the `Copy-Item` doesn't allow credentials. Now is possible to copy files through the sessions between servers:

```
$deploy_dest = "C:\backup"
$username = "$server\Administrator"
$password =  Get-Content C:\mypassword.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

$creds = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $password

$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $creds

Copy-Item -Path .\copy_test.txt -Destination -ToSession $session
```

Answer (score 1):

If credentials are required for access to a remote share you need to map it to a (PS)drive before you can use it with other cmdlets.

```
$cred = Get-Credential
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\$serverip\c$" -Credential $cred -Persist
Copy-Item '.\copy_test.txt' -Destination 'X:\backups'
Remove-PSDrive -Name X
```

Comment: @Robert If you want to use variables in the UNC path string you must put it in double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: I did it. Now in double quotes... the error is the same. So the quotes aren't the root of the problem.

Comment: Do I need to share the server folder in order to create the PSDrive?

Comment: Well, of course you cannot map a shared folder if that folder isn't shared in the first place. Note that `C$` is a administrative share, so the account you're authenticating with needs to have admin privileges on the remote host to be able to access it. If that's not the case you need to create a share that's accessible with the given credentials. Also make sure that the firewall(s) allows access to the share.

Answer (score 1):

Check this alternative using **copy** command and **net use**

```
net use \\10.164.60.77\c$\Users\ana\Desktop password /user:username
copy "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\test.txt" "\\10.164.60.77\c$\Users\ana\Desktop\test.txt"
```