# Powershell with MS SQL Copy-item to network drive

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I have a script that runs perfectly in a Job step of MS SQL besides one command.
With this command:

```
Copy-Item C:\Test\My_file.txt  \\NETWORK\FOLDER\DATA
```

This doesnt work in Powershell.exe.

I have tried also this:

```
$destination = "\\NETWORK\FOLDER\DATA"
Copy-Item C:\Test\My_file.txt $destination
```

When I run file where these lines are written, Powershell.exe works fine.

But
But it doesnt work. Dont you know what can be a problem with copying to Network drive?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably the account under which the job is executed?

Comment: Most likely it's the permissions on the network location for the user executing the script - I assume it's part of a backup procedure run by the SQL Agent user.

Comment: Dont you know how can it be checked? :)

Comment: Are you getting any errors ? If you do, please post them.

Comment: No, no errors .. It seems everything was successfully ended

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41617778/1630171).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thank you for a suggestion, I will try it tomorrow :)