# Identify unused network mapped drive

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm using PowerShell 5.1.14409.1012 and want to create a network drive using `New-PsDrive`.

To ensure that I create a mapped network drive that has not been used by the user, I use the following code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617778/copy-item-for-copy-files-from-local-to-remove-server-using-credentials)):

```
$used  = Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -Expand Name | Where-Object { $_.Length -eq 1 }
$drive = 90..65 | ForEach-Object { [string][char]$_ } |
         Where-Object { $used -notcontains $_ } |
         Select-Object -First 1
```

If I run `Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -Expand Name | Where-Object { $_.Length
-eq 1 }` the following is what displayed:

```
C
D
E
P
Q
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Z
```

The thing is, when I checked My Computer, there are a couple of drive letters currently disconnected:

[image: My Computer Network Drives]

As you can see, the `Get-PSDrive` does not pick up the disconnected network drive (such as "S" drive), and this has created the following error when I tried to connect to it:

[image: New-PSDrive error]

What's the best thing to capture the disconnected network drive?

Comment: Try my code for getting unused drive letters from this answer: [Powershell Function Not Mapping Drive When Called](//stackoverflow.com/a/44680810), I think it should deal with disconnected drives.

Comment: What does this returns: [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() | Format-Table

Answer (score 0):

A similar functionality already exist in [`Net Use'](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx): (Type an asterisk (*) instead of a specific device name to assign the next available device name.)

To get the actual selected drive name:

```
$Drive = (net use * \\Server\Share)[0][6]
```

You might also consider to use [Get-WMIObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1) to find the drives in use:

```
Get-WMIObject -query "Select * From Win32_LogicalDisk Where DriveType = 4" | Select-Object -Expand DeviceID
```